# Remove extra "Version" word from auto generated info in the iOS app

Tags: feature-request, bug, ios-app

When you submitting a bug for (and from) iOS app, app automatically adds information block to the post's body, e.g.:

> [image: ver]

As you can see word "Version" is doubling in OS section. I suggest to remove one of these, as I already did manually in current post.

- App Version: 1.6.4
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: 10.2.1 (Build 14D27)